# Why does a percentage width work on an :after pseudo element but not on :before?

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem where I'm trying to overlay images in the corners of a div. The code is setup like this:

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <img src="testImg.jpg" width="960" height="649">
        </div>
    <body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
img {
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
.container {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
}
.container:before {
    content:url(../topLeftCorner.png);
    height:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:7.3%;
}
.container:after {
    content:url(../bottomRightCorner.png);
    height:auto;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    width:7.3%;
}
```

As you might of guessed, I'm trying to make this responsive. The corners match the background color of the page (which in this case is white). They are png's and have half diagonally transparent so to make the top left and bottom right corners look like they are beveled (rather then using border-radius etc).

The problem is, the bottom right :after element DOES in fact scale with the parent, including the image... and it stays 7.3% of the width of the parent. the :before element on the other hand... the element scales.. but the image inside does NOT.

I can not figure this out for the life of me... it makes no sense at all. Why would a :after image scale (because of the max-width:100% on the img tag)... but not the image inside of the :before element???

This has been tested this in Chrome (latest stable release) and FireFox. Haven't yet tried it in other browsers.

Comment: oh yes sorry was a typo. It is corrected now.

Comment: Could you provide a jsFiddle showing the problem?